# No Log Output When Rails Server Started in Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

When I start the rails server in production mode and hit the root route, I get an error message and the server log remains unchanged.

I'm using `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` to start the program. It's a Rails 5.2 app.

When I start the server in development mode, everything works as expected.

I expect the `home#index` action to get hit as defined in `config/routes.rb`, which renders a simple template (unchanged from generating it previously).

Instead I see a 500 error in the network tab, and this message is displayed:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

Most troubling, I expect to at least see some changes in the server log but nothing happens.

Update: I'm sure no other server is running on the same port, using `lsof -i :3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set another environment variable and finally saw some output after a new request was issued:

`RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true RAILS_ENV=production rails s`